# I cannot edit my own post

Tags: support, bug

For some reason, I am unable to edit [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/24401/can-one-improve-his-chess-without-playing-online/24408#24408) post. There is an (obvious) typo in the beginning of it, but when I try to edit in the "Hello," nothing happens.

Not sure if this is a bug or an unexplainable fluke that will be better in a few minutes.

UPDATE:

I am *not* even kidding; this is super strange. I can edit *ANYTHING* else into the post, but when I try to add the phrase "Hello, and welcome to Chess.SE!" at the beginning of my answer (the question is from a new user), **the "Hello," part will not save, and it only says "and welcome to Chess.SE!"**

I'm kind of freaking out right now trying to get this to work.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvotes? The community on this site bugs me....Upvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salutations such as "Hello", "Hi", etc. in the beginning of the post is automatically stripped by the system.

This is explained more on [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989)

> We now automatically remove salutations from posts as they are entered.
>
> I got really tired of performing this edit over and over, so anything matching the form of …
>
> ```
> some RegEx patterns
> ```
>
> … is removed automagically at the time of submission to the server.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that's a standard check in the editor. The network wide policy is that hello, welcome, and similar words and phrases shouldn't be part of an answer, although I couldn't find a meta post to verify that.

Comment: Huh, thanks. I figured it would be OK since he was a new user.